# How to use google cloud text to speech api in android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I've got a problem with authentification for google CLOUD text to speech api. I can send a post request with curl easily with:

```
curl -X POST 
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \     
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -H "x-goog-user-project: text2speech" \
  https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize \     
  -d @request.json \
  -o synthesize-output-base64.txt
```

The problem seems to be `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`, the resulting access token changes.
My question is, how to do a post request from inside my app, since the gcloud tool is not available during runtime i suppose.
Constructing the post request is not an issue. It's about the authentification. I am really surprised how difficult this seems to be. Having said this I'm also relatively new to Android/Kotlin programming.
Thanks!

Comment: That access-token is you, and should be keep secure to avoid being leaked/stolen resulting in excess charges/API usage. So really it shouldn't be in the Android app. Your app, perhaps with a login/password/user account, would access your server which would make the call to Google Cloud APIs, get the data back and pass that back to your Android app. Google promotes Firebase which is their mobile solution for cloud. They also have codelabs to introduce their services https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?text=firebase%20android%20chat Be aware that the TTS API can be called from any server.

Comment: thanks for the warning. So, what you are saying is that in order to use their paid rest http service i need to use another paid service or build up a server infrastructure myself ? I am really surprised that its that difficult and there really is no way to directly let users send request to their api (I can create an API key but i still somehow need to use the token apparently). For google maps it seems to work more easily and i don't really see a significant difference here to speech synthetization to be honest.

Comment: For cloud services there is usually a free tier to give you a taste, but once apps go into production expect charges. On device Google allow for maps, but maps directions are a cloud service, and you can do on Android device TTS for free with the stock voices, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech but the more natural sounding is a cloud service.

Comment: I'm aware of the free tier and the android device text to speech, the better quality is exactly why i want to use the cloud option for the TTS, since its an integral part of the app. But it seems this is opening a box of pandora. Would rather have a more risky, less labour intensive solution with high quality to test if the app attracts any users in the first place..

Answer (score 1):

To help all poor souls that were stuck for way too long on this like me:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=<api_key> \
  -d @request.json \
  -o synthesize-output-base64.txt
```

this curl post request has worked for me.

API keys are listed here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<your_project_name>

You might need to create a new one if there is none.

As mentioned by Morrison Chang in the comment this might be a security risk for your app and I'm not sure if this is the way to do this in production.